# PHP Class, considered bad practice? setters and getters

Tags: php, class, oop

quick question:
Is it considered bad practice to set something in a Construct function like so:

```
Class whatever {

    $var = "";

    public function __construct($var){
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    //And then return it in another function like
    public function getVar(){
        return $this->var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that is the right way.

Comment: Is it just a good as if you were to make a function called setVar?? without a construct part?

Comment: No. Not at all. That’s what a constructor’s *for*.

Comment: Nothing of this is a bad practice, **but** I would not that stuff that you pass to the class in the constructor (the mandatory dependencies) are not usually the pulled out again via getters. If you pass pass something at the moment of initialization (like DB connection), then it usually is used internally/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is a good practice .

suppose you have 20 fields , and you must fill them to use class correctly .

good practice is to initialize them in the construction . if you use setter you must call 20 methods .

Comment: If you have a class with 20 fields you _must_ set individually, you have a bad design

Comment: I’d run a mile if I saw a class that takes 20 parameters. A class should do one thing and one thing well. If it needs 20 bits of data to function, it’s most likely inefficient.

Comment: i dont mean that you must get input from users for all of that fields , you should set value for them with some initial value .

Comment: @ Martin Bean : 20 is just an example . in my opinion 6 is alos inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is bad practice since you not declare `$var` and not are using a setter method. The meaning with getter and setter methods completely vanyshes when you not declare the variable, and not declare it private or protected. Then you could just go with `$class->var=something`.

```
Class whatever {
 private $var;

 public function __construct($var){
   $this->setVar($var);
 }

 public function setVar($var){
   $this->var = $var;
 }

 public function getVar(){
   return $this->var;
 }
}
```

Comment: well I do set my vars just didn't added into the expample

Answer (score -1):

You have good answers, but I'll give you a rundown on some more info

#### what is the constructor for?

Use a constructor in your classes if your class **instances** need initialization

- a getter for variables set in the constructor could be useful as a way to find out how the instance was initialized

#### setters

You need these when you need to modify the behaviour of your instance, or when you want to load data into it

#### getters

The only way to retrieve the contents of the instance (public properties are not encouraged due to a plethora of reasons)

#### My example

Feel free to do what you wish with this, it's only an example and it's obviously not doing anything. If you want to ask anything about this, please do

```
<?php
class AnExampleClass {
  // this is convenient sometimes but I don't recommend it
  public $public = '';
  protected $protected;
  private $private;
  public function __construct($private, $protected){
    $this->private = $private;
    $this->setProtected($protected);
  }
  public function getPrivate(){
    return $this->private;
  }
  public function getProtected() {
    return $this->protected;
  }
  public function setProtected($protected) {
    // only allow boolean
    $this->protected = (bool)$protected;
  }
  public function __get($name) {
    // read the manual on this magic
  }
  public function __set($name, $value) {
    // read the manual on this magic
  }
}
```